# Compile an old fortran code

Tags: compilation, fortran, virtual-machine

I need to compile an old (1992) fortran code. This code run in some SGI IRIX workstation and it was originally compiled with f77. I get errors if I try to compile it with gcc (g77) on my macbook pro or in a ubuntu virtual machine. I wonder if there is some way to get the old f77 compiler (virtual machine, whatever). f2c does not work at all.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? It's hard to suggest another, more up-to-date, compiler if we do not know what constructs can not be handled by e.g. `g77`.

Comment: If f2c doesn't work then it's almost certainly not f77. It no doubt is using some vendor specific extensions. Either remove the vendor specific code or find an SGI IRIX workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it is the case of some vendor extensions which modern compilers do not support (extremelly rare), I don't see why F77 code compilation & build should present any problem at all. Fortran IV or older, maybe, but F77 (within reasonable bounds) should work without much problems.

However, it is hard to suggest anything but a mere [list of compilers available](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Compilers) without knowing anything about it. The details of the code, the errors that you got, the compile options ... (?)

Please, post some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I sucessfully compiled some fortran77 source code from ~1992 with the Openwatcom Fortran compiler:
http://www.openwatcom.org/

more fortran compilers:
http://www.fortran.com/compilers.html

Comment: This doesn't mean anything. I too could have written a hello world program in 1992 and compiled it without problems today, with any Fortran compiler.